# How can I find the minimum deployment version for an iOS app target programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` only returns the current iOS version being run on. No way to get the minimum deployment version.

Comment: you can manually keep a constant like minimum_ios_version = "iOS_9" or enum and compare with it using current device version.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to find minimum deployment target with using `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` keyword. For example;

```
print(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)
//90300 -> 9.3
```

**Objective C**

```
    NSLog(@"Deployment target: %i", __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED);
```